# How to set expiration date for software in java?

Tags: java, security, cryptography

I write a small program in java.I know how to use Java date's class to write expiration date.However sometimes users change the computer time and pass this protection.Is there good way or logic for this? Thanks...

DETAILS:

- Software will work on customer software.
- There will be no internet connection.Just company network.
- Software will be 1 year licensing.

Comment: No. [filler to make comment 15 characters long]

Comment: Also, it's not Java-specific.

Comment: (Maybe you could limit the program starts instead of using time? Or limit the functionality?)

Comment: A simple trick is to look at the change data of a file that gets touched when the OS boots. That way a user needs to reboot to change the data. (Or change your application code, but there's no way around that no matter what you do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get current time on web service or web to avoid user manipulation.

Comment: If there is no internet what should I do?

Comment: AFAIK nothing to do.